# How to add checkbox for the first TD in each TR of HTML table using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to add Checkbox for the very first TD of each TR's in a table.
Assume that Table is as following

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery code :

```
 var tdCnt=0;
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $('<td>').append
        $('<input />', {
            type : 'checkbox',
            id : 'td' + tdCnt,
            class : 'dt-checkboxes',
            value : name
        }).appendTo($(this));
        $('</td>').appendTo($(this));
        tdCnt++;
    });
```

Help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Nope! Its just a dummy variable, Ignore that

Comment: You haven't defined a problem. Your code basically works but no need to try to append a closing tag

Comment: No, The checkbox is appended for all the TD's, What i need is for the first TD only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending to row. Where as you are saying

> I need to add Checkbox for the very first TD of each TR's in a table.

Then it should be

```
}).appendTo($(this).find("td").eq(0));
```

```js
var tdCnt=0;
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $('<input />', {
            type : 'checkbox',
            id : 'td' + tdCnt,
            class : 'dt-checkboxes',
            value : name
        }).appendTo($(this).find("td").eq(0));
        tdCnt++;
    });
```

```css
.dt-checkboxes {
float :left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also you are appending another empty td too.  `$('</td>').appendTo($(this));` removed.

Comment: This worked like a charm, and is it possible to align the checkbox to the right of that TD

Comment: No need for a new `<td>` ... can't nest `<td>`

Comment: @charlietfl True, haven't noticed it. Edited.

Comment: @eThan_hunT There you go.

Comment: Hi Suresh Atta, Can u please help me to answer the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918995/how-to-get-the-td-having-the-rowspan-with-value-and-split-into-individual-td-usi

Comment: @SureshAtta - What if I have only **one** table column and want add a **second** column for the *checkbox** to be placed in. How may I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use first selector:

```js
var tdCnt=0;
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').first().append(
    $('<input />', {
        type : 'checkbox',
        id : 'td' + tdCnt,
        class : 'dt-checkboxes',
        value : name
    }));
    tdCnt++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi @amicoderozer , can u please help me to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918995/how-to-get-the-td-having-the-rowspan-with-value-and-split-into-individual-td-usi

Answer (score 0):

```
var tdCnt = 0;
$('table tr').each(function(index, element){
    $(this).prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" id="chckBox_'+tdCnt+'" class="chckClass_'+tdCnt+'" value="" /></td>');
    tdCnt++;
});
```

Comment: `<input>` is invalid child of `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append(function)` and target the `first-child`. The first argument of the callback is `index` and will increment each iteration

```js
$('table tr :first-child').append(function(i) {
  return $('<input />', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'td' + i,
    class: 'dt-checkboxes',
    value: name
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="ckec"> </td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var count = 0;
                $('table tr').each(function () {
                    jQuery(this).find('td').first().html('<input type="checkbox" name="ckec" id="test' + count + '">');
count++;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any doubt.